# Mute Command with Time Limit

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering how I can make my mute command mute someone for a certain amount of time.  For example `p/mute @User 1h` would mute someone for 1 hour.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
  if member == None:
    await ctx.send("Please mention a user to mute")
  else:
    user = member
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if role is None:
      await ctx.send("Please make a muted role name `Muted` or make sure to name the role `Muted` and not `muted` or `MUTED`")
    else:
      await user.add_roles(role)
      await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been muted by {ctx.author.name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

[This site](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/discord.py+mute) has an example on one way to do this, however I found it needed some slight modifications to work - it was giving me errors in some spots prior to my edits. Below code worked in my server:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['tempmute'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, time=None, *, reason=None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("You must mention a member to mute!")
        return
    elif not time:
        await ctx.send("You must mention a time!")
        return
    else:
        if not reason:
            reason="No reason given"
        #Now timed mute manipulation
    try:
        time_interval = time[:-1] #Gets the numbers from the time argument, start to -1
        duration = time[-1] #Gets the timed manipulation, s, m, h, d
        if duration == "s":
            time_interval = time_interval * 1
        elif duration == "m":
            time_interval = time_interval * 60
        elif duration == "h":
            time_interval = time_interval * 60 * 60
        elif duration == "d":
            time_interval = time_interval * 86400
        else:
            await ctx.send("Invalid duration input")
            return
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ctx.send("Invalid time input")
        return
    guild = ctx.guild
    Muted = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not Muted:
        Muted = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(Muted, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True, read_messages=False)
    else:
        await member.add_roles(Muted, reason=reason)
        muted_embed = discord.Embed(title="Muted a user", description=f"{member.mention} Was muted by {ctx.author.mention} for {reason} to {time}")
        await ctx.send(embed=muted_embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(int(time_interval))
        await member.remove_roles(Muted)
        unmute_embed = discord.Embed(title='Mute over!', description=f'{ctx.author.mention} muted to {member.mention} for {reason} is over after {time}')
        await ctx.send(embed=unmute_embed)
```

This should create a new role called "Muted" in your server if it doesn't already exist, move the targeted member into said role for the time denoted, and then remove them from the role once time expires.

Example command using code (prefix of `.`):

`.tempmute @SomeUser 10s Because I said so!`

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty easy way of doing that. That will be efficient and less code required. I have been using that in my Bots for a long time. I have answered another question of the one user here: [Bot unmuting member when use tempmute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415783/bot-unmuting-member-when-use-tempmute-command/67417026#67417026)

In the answer there I have explained on how to write a perfect command.

**This command is completely another command. You don't have to modify your `mute` command. But just create a new command named `tempmute`.**

I will copy and paste my answer from there to here. Please pay attention to every single statement. :)

### TEMPMUTE Command.

#### Step 1: Define the function and permissions

We are going to define the function with some permissions restrictions on the use. People with the permissions specified permissions.

Before you use this, you need to have the following in your code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

(Ignore if you have it)

Here is how:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time, *, reason=None):
```

You can add many more permission if you want and use True or False to allow or deny.

#### Step 2: Making a role finding condition. If the role doesn't exist then create a Muted role, if exist then use it.

So I am creating a condition for if the role exist. It will check if the role exist. If it exist then we will simply use it but if it doesn't we will create one with specific permissions.

Here is how:

```
if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted"):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
else:
    perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, add_reactions=False, connect=False, speak=False)
    await bot.create_role(name="Muted", permissions=perms)
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
```

#### Step 3: Checking if someone is muted or not.

Now I am creating a condition for if the member is muted or not. We will through the member's roles and check it.

Here is how:

```
if mute_roles in member.roles:
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member.mention} is already muted!")
else:
    # code here (more steps will explain how)
```

### Step 4: Adding conditions and muting the member.

Now we will add restriction permissions for this command. Who all people can't be muted and who all can be.

First we add our first condition, that administrators can not be muted.
Here is how:

```
if member.guild_permissions.administrator:    
    isadminembed=discord.Embed(title="Tempmute", description=f"Hi {ctx.author.mention}, you can't mute {member.mention} as they are a Server Administrator.", color=discord.Colour.red())
    isadminembed.set_author(name="Bot")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=isadminembed)
```

Now we will add `else` condition, that all other members except administrators can be muted.
Here is how:

```
else:
    time_conversion = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400, "w": 604800, "M": 2419200, "y": 29030400}
    mute_time = int(time[:-1]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]

    await member.add_roles(mute_role)
    mutedembed=discord.Embed(title="Tempmute", description=f"The member, {member.mention} has been muted by the moderator {ctx.author.mention}. \n \nTime: {mute_time} seconds \nReason: {reason}", color=discord.Colour.random())
    mutedembed.set_author(name="Bot")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=mutedembed)

    await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
    await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member.mention} has been unmuted!")
```

I have added time conversion here. The time input has to be:

`1s` for one second, `1m` for one minute, etc. You can use it for `years` too.

---

### Tempmute Command Compiled

This is all the code compiled together as the command.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time, *, reason=None):
    if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted"):
        mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    else:
        perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, add_reactions=False, connect=False, speak=False)
        await bot.create_role(name="Muted", permissions=perms)
        mute_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")

    if mute_roles in member.roles:
        await ctx.channel.send(f"{member.mention} is already muted!")
    
    else:
        if member.guild_permissions.administrator:    
            isadminembed=discord.Embed(title="Tempmute", description=f"Hi {ctx.author.mention}, you can't mute {member.mention} as they are a Server Administrator.", color=discord.Colour.red())
            isadminembed.set_author(name="Bot")
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=isadminembed)
        
        else:
            time_conversion = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400, "w": 604800, "M": 2419200, "y": 29030400}
            mute_time = int(time[:-1]) * time_conversion[time[-1]]

            await member.add_roles(mute_role)
            mutedembed=discord.Embed(title="Tempmute", description=f"The member, {member.mention} has been muted by the moderator {ctx.author.mention}. \n \nTime: {mute_time} seconds \nReason: {reason}", color=discord.Colour.random())
            mutedembed.set_author(name="Bot")
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=mutedembed)

            await asyncio.sleep(mute_time)
            await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
            await ctx.channel.send(f"{member.mention} has been unmuted!")
```

---

### TEMPMUTE Command Error Handling

#### Step 1: Defining the function as an event.

We will define the function in the script as tempmute command's error and declare it as an error.

Here is how:

```
@bot.error
async def tempmute_error(ctx, error):
```

#### Step 2: Adding the instance of the error.

We will now add a condition for the error. Our error will be: `MissingRequiredArgument` error as the command can lack necessary arguments.

So the `isinstance` will check the error and then do the stuff.

Here is how:

````
if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    tempmuteerrorembed=discord.Embed(title=f"Missing Argument! {error}", description=f"Hello {ctx.author.mention}! You have not entered the needed argument. \n Either you forgot to **mention the member** or you forgot to **enter the time of the mute** you want. \n \n Please check this again and add the necessary argument in the command. \n \nThis is the syntax: \n```!tempmute <mention member> <time: 1s, 2h, 4y etc..> <reason (optional)>```", color=discord.Colour.red())
    tempmuteerrorembed.set_author(name="Bot")
    await ctx.send(embed=tempmuteerrorembed)
````

This will work for `MissingRequiredArguement` and show the error with the syntax in it for the command's correct usage.

---

### TEMPMUTE Command Error Handling Compiled

Here is the compiled code of Error Handling of TEMPMUTE Command.

````
@bot.error
async def tempmute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        tempmuteerrorembed=discord.Embed(title=f"Missing Argument! {error}", description=f"Hello {ctx.author.mention}! You have not entered the needed argument. \n Either you forgot to **mention the member** or you forgot to **enter the time of the mute** you want. \n \n Please check this again and add the necessary argument in the command. \n \nThis is the syntax: \n```!tempmute <mention member> <time: 1s, 2h, 4y etc..> <reason (optional)>```", color=discord.Colour.red())
        tempmuteerrorembed.set_author(name="Bot")
        await ctx.send(embed=tempmuteerrorembed)
````

---

I hope I was able to explain to you the answer and how to write the command. Please ask in the comments for any issue that arises.

Thank You! :D